# migrate from jboss 7 to wildfly24 how validate and fix standalone.xml (element with jboss:domain:messaging-activemq )

Tags: xml, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

I am currently trying to migrate a Jboss 7. Main part is to migrate the standalone xml.
While many parts still work others do not.

Currently i added a this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
  ...
</subsystem>
```

what caused (**edited**):

```
OPVDX001: Validierungsfehler in standalone.xml ---------------------------------
|
|  484:     </mail-session>
|  485: </subsystem>
|  486: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
|       ^^^^ Unexpected element
|              '{urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0}subsystem'
|
|  487:     <server name="default">
|  488:         <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="1234"/>
|  489:         <remote-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
|
| Die primõre zugrunde liegende Fehlermeldung lautete:
| > ParseError at [row,col]:[486,9]
| > Message: Unexpected element
| >   '{urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0}subsystem'
|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

14:31:51,479 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:403)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

14:31:51,481 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

What is not helpful at all.

My questions are:

specific:
Can some one tell specifically (or link docs) how to migrate this part of XML

general (i guess it will not be the last validation error i will hit):
What is a good approach to migrate the xml, validate and fix it? Is it possible to get more detailed error? Is it possible validate in external tools? Is there a tool for migrating those XML files?

Comment: You have a default namespace that has to be used to parse the xml using standard libraries.

Comment: you mean "xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:17.0" ? how does this help to find the error

Comment: The request is not getting parsed properly because the namespace which is cause of error.  You did not post any code.  Did you update the WSDL?  See namespaces in following : https://developer.jboss.org/thread/100367

Comment: i used the standalone.xml shipped with wildfly 24. and wildfly is starting fine. but adding the subsytsem "jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0" causes the error. i guess i need to change this - but what to change- changing to messaging-activemq:13.0 didn't help

Comment: You need to add the namespace to first line of WSDL like in the link I provided.  The namespace in the xml is same as the WSDL

Comment: this is no wsdl, this is just an xml - a configuration. the xml file is given and valid. it is just about to add an element - another "subsystem" element.

Comment: The namespace has to be consistent with the xsd schema.  See Para 9.1 https://docs.wildfly.org/24/Admin_Guide.html#application-deployment

Comment: and since i did not change it, it should be consistent. i cheange the urn to messaging-activemq:13.0 - what is consistent too

Comment: The namespace `xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0"` has  schema and the schema has to pass.  Changing versions you have to use a compatible schema.

Answer (score 1):

You should not copy the entire subsystem been versions but use the standalone-full file for wildfly to include the messaging subsystem, but then only add the specific elements you need, for example adding a topic or queue

In general you are much better leaning to use the cli and use a cli script to make the changes you need rather than hacking the raw XML

E.g

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] jms-queue add --queue-address=myQueue --entries=queues/myQueue

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Messaging%20configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The hint came from https://developer.jboss.org/thread/169838

The element "subsystem" was not the problem. But the extension for "urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0" was missing.

Adding

```
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>
```

in extensions element solved this problem.